# Separating <td> in a <tr> using jquery when pulled from an onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

Before we start I am fairly new to jquery and do not know most of the functions and capability, so I do not know if there is an easy trick to do this that I am missing.

I am having an issue where I am using a search function to display a table of results using Jquery, ajax and PHP. Once the results table is displayed from the search, I have a clickable link on the final row of the table. This link should get the data from the row you clicked on and set it to a `$_SESSION` in PHP. I can get the correct data fine, I just cannot separate out each `<td>` field individually. I wish to do this by adding in a comma or a symbol that I could use to identify each separate field once in PHP. This is an issue as I wish to put it into an array to auto-fill some input on the next page that you get redirected too. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction for this.

**Jquery + ajax**

```
$('#resultviews').on("click",".buttonaslink",function(){
var tabler = $(this).closest("tr").text();
tabler = ('tabler=' + tabler);  
alert(tabler);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "rowsession.php",
data: tabler,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$('#resultviews').html(html).show();
}});
return false;
});
```

**PHP how results are displayed in the table from first ajax POST**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($view)){
    $id = $row['companyId'];
    $company = $customers[$id];
    $company = ucwords($company);

    echo "<tr><td class='tabled'>". $row['ip']."</td><td class='table'>". $row['Subnet']."</td><td class='table'>".$row['hostName']."</td><td class='table'>". $row['owner']."</td><td class='table'>". $company ."</td><td class='table'>".$row['siteName']."</td><td class='table'><button id='rowbtn' class='buttonaslink'>Edit</button> / <button id='rowdel' class='btnaslink'>del</button><tr>";
    }
```

Comment: I guess, if you need to show something in the next page, does not better to get only the ID of your row and get the data from PHP? if you get the data from the table, anyone can change this data and crack you app. if this could work for you, just put a mark on the TD with the ID value and get it like this: $(this).closest("tr").find(".identifier")

Comment: @damianfabian But how would I then see the data in that specific row? I need to be able to set a session to the data in the row for essentially filling in inputs on the directed to page. I escape what comes in from the ajax POST so i am not to concerned about that being an issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
var tabler = $(this).closest("tr").find("td")
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  })
  .get()
  .join(",");
```

It takes a value from every *td* element of the row and joins them with a comma. If you need to remove a trailing comma, you can use this code:

```
if(tabler.length) {
    tabler = tabler.substring(0, tabler.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: You are a god among men, Thank you so much ^.^ marking it as right :)